# Redirect URL in Android app using Microsoft

Tags: android, redirect, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I am currently developing an android app requiring the power of Microsoft authentication and its API Graph. The objective is to offer users the possibility to find friends into the same tenant (i.e University) by using Graph.

However, there is something I didn't actually understand about redirect URLs we have to add on Azure App registration. My colleagues cannot make request using my URL specified into the JSON provided by Azure:

```
{
  "client_id" : "a50XXXXXXXX",
  "authorization_user_agent" : "BROWSER",
  "redirect_uri" : "msauth://com.example.myfirstapp/OizXXXXXXXXXX",
  "broker_redirect_uri_registered" : true,
  "account_mode" : "SINGLE",
  "authorities" : [
    {
      "type": "AAD",
      "audience": {
        "type": "AzureADMyOrg",
        "tenant_id": "8b8XXXXXXXXXXX"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Do all developers have to specify a different redirect URL based on their project signature ? It seems to be weird because once the app in production launched, there will be only one redirect URL ...

To make things clearer, I followed this tutorial about using Graph and MSAL according to android app development:
[Microsoft Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-android)

However, when colleagues clone the repo and run the app, they are getting an error about false redirect_uri. They have to compute their hash signature of the project and register this redirect uri on Microsoft Azure.

Here is the portion of code used to compute the hash signature:

```kotlin
    try {
    val info = packageManager.getPackageInfo(
        "com.example.myfirstapp",
        PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES)
    for (signature in info.signatures) {
        val md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA")
        md.update(signature.toByteArray())
        Log.d("KeyHash", "KeyHash:" + Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(),
        Base64.DEFAULT))
    }
        }
    catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
    Log.d("LOGIN_TAG","NameNotFoundException")
    }
    catch (e: NoSuchAlgorithmException) {
        Log.d("LOGIN_TAG","NoSuchAlgorithmException")
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the error message when you make the request.

Comment: One redirect URL is for one application.  Just specifying the same signature hash and redirect URL should be OK. Please share the error message as @ChethanM suggested.

Comment: Okay, here is the error I'm getting when running the app: ```com.microsoft.identity.client.exception.MsalClientException: The redirect URI in the configuration file doesn't match with the one generated with package name and signature hash. Please verify the uri in the config file and your app registration in Azure portal.``` To make things clearer, my colleagues clone the repository and use the same instance on same branch. However, according to [Microsoft Tutorial]{https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-android} we need to specify hash signature of project

Comment: Did your colleagues generate new signature hash and redirect URL and configure them in the app registration and the project? Or just run the project without any changes?

Comment: First, they run the project with same files as mine. Because of the previous error, they have to generate new signature hash, specify these signature on Microsoft AD, modify JSON config files and rerun. And then, it works ...

Comment: I'm sure that if they generate new signature hash, it should work. But if they don't do any changes, the redirect URLs in AAD app and the project should also match with each other.

Comment: Yes, as you said, it works if they generate new hash signature but it is not what we want. If there are many developers, they will be many hash and that is not we want. According to Microsoft, there is two different hash for Android project (debugging and normal ones). I think I will find the explanation soon provided by Microsoft employees

Answer (score 0):

Let us explain the problem properly. There are in fact two different hashes when registering an app on Azure portail.

- One is used for developing the app and all developers have to specify their own signature because their environment differ.
- One is used for releasing your app in production. This kind of hash is unique and all developers can use the same hash.

In case of an Android app, Android studio will compute a debug key which is not what we want when releasing in production mode. The portion of code provided above computes a debug hash which is in fact linked with the development hash signature called by Microsoft.

below a screenshot of the panel displayed on the Azure portail where you can find these two hashes:

[Microsoft Azure Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESnFg.png)
To conclude, be careful of what you want and what Microsoft provides.